# Systems with trivial cohomology

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

If $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is an irrational number, then the rotation $X = (S^1, +\alpha)$ has "trivial" cohomology i.e. 
$$H^1(X) := C(X,\mathbb{C})/\beta C(X,\mathbb{C})$$
consists only of scalar multiples of the class $[1]$ of the constant function (where $C(X,\mathbb{C})$ is the additive group of complex-valued continuous functions on $X$ and $\beta g(x) = g(x+\alpha)-g(x)$ is the coboundary map). My question is, does this property characterizes irrational rotations? More precisely: let $X$ be compact metrizable and $T\colon X\to X$ an homeomorphism such that $(X,T)$ is minimal and $H^1(X,T)$ trivial (in the sense of above). Then, is $(X,T)$ conjugated, in some sense, to $(S^1,+\alpha)$, for some $\alpha$? or at least to a more general group rotation?

Comment: "other minimal group rotations"? but the minimal group rotations are precisely the irrational rotations. What is the question?

Comment: If $X = (G,\cdot a)$ is a group rotatation such that the orbit $\{a^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $G$, isn't it $G$ minimal?

Comment: My question is: if $(X,T)$ is a topological dynamical system such that $H^1(X)$ is trivial then, is $(X,T)$ conjugated in some sense to $(S^1,+\alpha)$, for some $\alpha$?

Comment: Well, can you edit your question so as to present the setting. I have no idea if you work on the circle or more general spaces/ compact group, and which which restrictions on the homeomorphism. The $H^1$ you define works for an arbitrary self-homeomorphism of a compact space, then can be specified to rotations of the circle. (By the way, $H^1(X)=\mathbf{C}$ is not trivial, it's 1-dimensional. For more general group actions, the space of co-invariants might be 0-dimensional.)

Comment: Aren't you precisely asking which systems $(X,T)$ are uniquely ergodic? Uniquely ergodic means that the only positive invariant linear forms on $C(X)$ are positive scalar multiples of "taking the integral" with respect to a given invariant measure. So clearly your condition implies uniquely ergodic, but I was wondering whether the converse also holds. It seems so: if one has a invariant signed measure, its positive and negative mutually singular parts are invariant too. So if this is correct there is plethora of examples beyond irrational rotations.

Comment: I see why my condition implies uniquely ergodicity, but not the converse. Actually, in https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.07700 the authors prove that some "S-adic systems of rank $K$" are such that $H^1$ has dimension $K$ as vector space, and I know that this kind of systems are uniquely ergodic. So, if I understood everything right, the converse is false.

Comment: Maybe my confusion comes from the possibility that $\beta C(X)$ might be non-closed. What my argument (if correct) proves is indeed that unique ergodicity means that the closure of $\beta C(X)$ is a hyperplane.